# a flag for testing if a generator is "running", and/or already exhausted

Tags: python, generator

### Summary

What I am after is a way of determining if the generator is "currently running".

### Details

My definition of "currently running" is:

1. The generator code has begun execution (i.e., `next` or `.send(None)` or some other iteration operation such as a for loop, has previously been executed on the generator, AND
2. the generator was not *previously* exhausted/closed (again note that for the above generator, `.throw(some_error)` is caught and will not exhaust the generator since some new loop is started; without a loop or `yield from` a handled error will usually exhaust the generator).

I understand that there is not a way (or at least, a trivially easy way) to "peek" ahead in a generator and find out if it will raise `StopIteration` at the next iteration. This is antithetical to the nature of the generator and is *NOT* what I am after.

### Example

Say I have some generator, `g` created by some generator function, `f`:

```
def f():
    '''Lots of 1s.'''
    print('I am now running.')
    while True:
        try:
            signal = yield 1
            if signal:
                break
        except GeneratorExit:
            raise #  important so that closing the generator doesn't cause a RuntimeError
        except Exception:
            print('caught exception!')
```

We can "initialize" the generator this  way:

```
>>> g = f()
>>> next(g)
I am now running.
1

# OR:

>>> g.send(None) #  equivalent to next(g)
I am now running.
1
```

If I send anything truthy into the generator, the `StopIteration` error is raised (e.g., `g.send('foo')`). Alternatively, if I call `g.close()`, and then do `next(g)`, I will also get `StopIteration`. If I throw any errors with `g.throw(e)`, the generator will continue. This is all as expected.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like the following, which shows whether or not this generator is running:

```
>>> g=f()
>>> g.running
False
>>> g.send(None)
I am now running.
1
>>> g.running
True
>>> g.close()
>>> g.running
False
```

I have provided one possible approach in an answer. However, I think there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inspect.getgeneratorstate` tells you the state of your generator:

```
>>> import inspect
... 
... def gen():
...     yield 1
...     
... g = gen()
...
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_CREATED'
>>> next(g)
1
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_SUSPENDED'
>>> next(g)
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(g)
'GEN_CLOSED'
```

Comment: Glorious- I *KNEW* there had to be something like that out there.

Answer (score 0):

My only idea is some kind of generator wrapper with methods that delegate to a stored generator, but this is a bit unwieldy. It might look something like this (haven't tested this):

```
class MyGen():
    '''Generator wrapper with 'exhausted' and 'running' flags.'''
    def __new__(cls, some_func):
        cls._func = some_func
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exhausted = False
        self.running = False
        self.start(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
    def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._gen = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            self.running = True
            next(self._gen)
        except StopIteration:
            self.exhausted = True
            self.running = False
            raise
    def send(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.running = True
            self._gen.send(*args, **kwargs)
        except StopIteration:
            self.exhausted = True
            self.running = False
            raise
    def throw(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self._gen.throw(*args, **kwargs)
        except StopIteration:
            self.exhausted = True
            self.running = False
            raise
    def close(self):
        self._gen.close()
        self.exhausted = True
        self.running = False
```

You could even use this as a decorator:

```
@MyGen
def f():
    yield 1
```

I really don't like this because it seems like there really should be an existing place to look for a "generator exhausted"  or "generator running" flag.